# Recursively re-encode .mp4 files to new copies of .mp4 and convert .mp4 to .webm and .ogg using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, ogg, webm

I have about 300 videos in `.mp4` files that I need re-encode as new `.mp4` files and to convert them to `.webm` and `.ogg` files.

I want to do it at the command line using `ffmpeg`, and I have the following command that converts the `.mp4` into a `.webm`.

```
find ./ -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -cpu-used 5 -threads 8 "${0%%.mp4}.webm"' {} \;
```

Can someone help me modify this command to two separate commands, one for `.mp4 -> .mp4` (suffixing the filename with `-2`) and another for `.mp4 -> .ogg`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I didn't get any replies, I did find the answer myself.

So, for the benefit of others looking to do the same thing, here are the various commands I put together:

```
webm
find ./ -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -vf scale=-1:480 -cpu-used 5 -threads 8 "${0%%.mp4}.webm"' {} \;
ogv
find ./ -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis -vf scale=-1:480 -cpu-used 5 -threads 8 "${0%%.mp4}.ogv"' {} \;
flv
find ./ -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -c:v libx264 -ar 22050 -crf 28 -vf scale=-1:480 -cpu-used 5 -threads 8 "${0%%.mp4}.flv"' {} \;
mp4
find ./ -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=-1:480 -cpu-used 5 -threads 8 "${0%%.mp4}-2.mp4"' {} \;
jpg
find ./ -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -ss 00:00:10 -vframes 1 -r 1 -vf scale=-1:480 -f image2 "${0%%.mp4}.jpg"' {} \;
```

Note that I have added the flag `-vf scale=-1:480` which scales the video proportionately. I have set the height to 480px and the width is automatically calculated.

Also, note that I have also included a screenshot export from each video. The capture is made at the 10th second of the video and is saved as a jpeg file.

If you would like to retain the dates of the original files so that the new version (.webm, .ogv, .mp4, .flv) have the same modification dates, you can use the `touch` command as follows:

`touch -r oldfile newfile`